# How to sum and avg where two fields are same?

Tags: sql, select, sum, compare, average

**Script:**

```
SELECT
m.order,
d.product,
d.nto,
p.code,
p.weight,
p.country
FROM so_order_master m
JOIN so_order_detail d ON d.order_id = m.id
JOIN product p ON p.product = s.product
```

**Current result:**

```
ORDER    PRODUCT         NTO        CODE         WEIGHT  COUNTRY
5014221  Z81-2R2R-1R     32,7303    3913 38 98   2,05    US
5014222  XX-811-RR4      26,2851    1718 19 81   4       US
5014222  12X-8-R7R81     2,4969     8489 91 88   0,035   TW
5014222  XX-4X8-RR1      19,0404    1718 19 81   1,2     SE
5014222  XX-84Y          18,8436    1718 19 81   1,5     US
5014222  YR7-Y147        61,1064    8489 91 88   0,4     TW
5014222  XX-8R8-RR4      63,9846    1718 19 81   4       US
5014222  XX-8R4-RR4      26,2851    1718 19 81   3       US
```

I would need help getting a script that:

- Sums the `NTO` fields with the same Code AND Country;
- Averages the `weight` fields with the same Code AND Country;
- Order and Product may be from the first row (not essential).

**Expected result:**

```
ORDER     PRODUCT       NTO_SUM     CODE        WEIGHT_AVG  COUNTRY
5014222   XX-4X8-RR1    19,0404     1718 19 81  1,2         SE
5014222   XX-811-RR4    135,3984    1718 19 81  3,125       US
5014221   Z81-2R2R-1R   32,7303     3913 38 98  2,05        US
5014222   12X-8-R7R81   63,6033     8489 91 88  0,2175      TW
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `GROUP BY Code, Country` etc.

Answer (score 2):

As you mention you should aggregate by "Code AND Country". Your query should be:

```
select
  max(m.order) as ordr,
  max(d.product) as product,
  sum(d.nto) as nto,
  p.code,
  avg(p.weight) as weight,
  p.country
from so_order_master m
join so_order_detail d on d.order_id = m.id
join product p on p.product = s.product
group by p.code, p.country
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [aggragate functions](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-aggregate-functions/) together with `GROUP BY` instruction. See:

```
select MAX(m.order), MAX(d.product), SUM(d.nto) AS nto_sum, p.code, AVG(p.weight) AS weight_avg, p.country
from so_order_master m
join so_order_detail d on d.order_id = m.id
join product p on p.product = s.product
GROUP BY p.code, p.country
```

Depending on database provider average function is available under `AVG()` or `AVERAGE()` name.

Comment: You should group by "Code AND Country" only.

Comment: @TheImpaler, Thank you. Query has been improved.